# LinAlgError: not positive definite, even with jitter

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, gaussian

I am trying to use Gaussian process regression on a cancer dataset using GPy, but the problem is when I fit a combination of 3 or 4 kernels the system collapses and gives the `LinAlgError: not positive definite, even with jitter` error. But it produces some output when I use a combination of two kernels. Here is the main code and the dataset image(the year in x-axis and tumor count in y-axis) I am trying to predict is attached below:

[image]

```
k_rbf = GPy.kern.RBF(1, lengthscale=50,name = "rbf")
k_exp = GPy.kern.Exponential(1,lengthscale=6)
k_lin = GPy.kern.Linear(1)
k_per = GPy.kern.StdPeriodic(1, period = 5)

k =   k_rbf * k_per + k_lin + k_exp

m = GPy.models.GPRegression(X, Y, k)

m.optimize()
def plot_gp(X, m, C, training_points=None):
    """ Plotting utility to plot a GP fit with 95% confidence interval """
    # Plot 95% confidence interval 
    plt.fill_between(X[:,0],
                     m[:,0] - 1.96*np.sqrt(np.diag(C)),
                     m[:,0] + 1.96*np.sqrt(np.diag(C)),
                     alpha=0.5)
    # Plot GP mean and initial training points
    plt.plot(X, m, "-")
    plt.legend(labels=["GP fit"])

    plt.xlabel("x"), plt.ylabel("f")

    # Plot training points if included
    if training_points is not None:
        X_, Y_ = training_points
        plt.plot(X_, Y_, "kx", mew=2)
        plt.legend(labels=["GP fit", "sample points"])
X_ = np.linspace(X.min(), X.max() + 30, 1000)[:, np.newaxis]

mean, Cov = m.predict(X_, full_cov=True)

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
plot_gp(X_, mean, Cov)
plt.gca().set_xlim([1990,2060]), plt.gca().set_ylim([35000, 150000])
plt.plot(X, Y, "b.");
```